# How to fix sizes before a page will be shown to the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my page was loaded I wanna get a height of `navbar` and update `padding-top` of my content. But if I will make it on `ready()` event the user will see a page before update and after it will be shown with new dimensions.
How to fix it before the page will be shown?

Comment: what is the condition for adding this CSS? why can't you add the CSS as is in the header for example?

Comment: @ShirGans, Its content is generating dynamically, I can't know before a height of my `navbar`.

Comment: Seems like you need a pre-loader or hide the full page and reveal it after the change

Comment: @ShirGans, I thought to show `navbar` and after content with updated size already but I hoped JS has another solution.

Comment: @ShirGans, thank you! Seems no way, I'll use a pre-loader then.

Comment: May be rethink your markup and clean it up. In my experience one jQuery band-aid will almost always need another...and may be one more, just one more... :)

Comment: can you not just set relative sizes (e.g. using % or em) rather than absolute sizes? Without seeing the existing code it's hard to be sure, but it sounds like you're trying to keep things in proportion depending on the user's screen size, which CSS can do quite easily if you declare things the right way.

Comment: The maximum number of lines in my `navbar` is two but I don't know whether it will have one or two, so the best variant for me now it's a pre-loader using if JS doesn't allow to updates sizes before page rendering.